# Refresh Chrome page without function keys

Tags: google-chrome, function-keys, tablet-mode

I have a Windows 10 tablet (Dell Latitude) with chrome, I have to force the page reload without cache (CTRL-F5) but I don't have the keyboard but just the built-in on screen keyboard without function keys. How can I refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You might be overlooking the already present <kbd>Fn</kbd> key**

The function keys can be turned on by default under your keyboard settings or simply toggled by hitting the lower left <kbd>Fn</kbd> key :)

If you do not see an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, then adjust your keyboard settings...

**Adjusting on-screen keyboard settings:**

1. Open the Settings app. (You can do this from the Start menu.)
2. Click or tap Devices.
3. Click or tap Typing.
4. Toggle on "Add the standard keyboard layout as a touch keyboard option."
5. Now click or tap the keyboard icon in the taskbar. - If you don't see that icon, right-click or long-press on the taskbar and select "Show touch keyboard button."
6. Click or tap the keyboard button at the bottom right of the on-screen keyboard.
7. Select the standard keyboard icon. It's the right-most icon.

**Consider a plugin**

Also, you might want to consider the "[Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en)" plugin, which you could toggle on and then refresh, and of course use day to day if cache is an ongoing problem for you (it is for me!)

Comment: In the win10 build-in keyboard I don't find the Fn key.

Comment: Hi Tobia, please see my edit for instructions regarding the alteration of your on-screen keyboard settings. There is a visual guide here: http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/full-layout-touch-keyboard-windows-10

Comment: Ah! Superb. Glad we got it solved :)